# Laravel 4.2 returning a json response with Auth::onceBasic()

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

So I have a before filter on my REST API request like the following:

```
Route::filter('auth.api', function() {
    Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
    return Auth::onceBasic('username');
});
```

This works perfectly for me except that I would rather it return a json response. So I tried surrounding it in `Request::json()` and that failed miserably. I then thought I could possibly make an AFTER filter that returns the response as json. However, I have no way of finding out if authentication was successful or not at that point.

```
Route::filter('auth.api.after', function($request, $response) {
    die(var_dump($response));
});
```

I want to respond with json on failure. How can I do this?

Working code:

```
Route::filter('auth.api', function() {
    Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
    $response = Auth::onceBasic('username');

    if (!is_null($response)) {
        $failMessage = [
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Invalid Credentials'
        ];

        $headers = ['WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic'];
        return Response::json($failMessage, 401, $headers);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Auth::onceBasic`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php#L287) returns either a response (if it fails) or null (if it succeeds). Creating a json response from that is not possible.

You need to first check if auth succeeds, and if so get the user with another method.

```
Route::filter('auth.api', function() {
    Config::set('session.driver', 'array');

    // Return the response onceBasic gives us if auth fails, otherwise get the current logged in user and turn it into a json response.
    return Auth::onceBasic('username') ?: Response::json(Auth::user()->toArray());
});
```

If you always want to return a json response, simply check if `onceBasic` returns `null`.

```
Route::filter('auth.api', function() {
    Config::set('session.driver', 'array');

    // If onceBasic doesn't return null, it means auth failed.
    if (null !== Auth::onceBasic('username')) {
        $message = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid credentials'];
        $headers = ['WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic'];

        return Response::json($message, 401, $headers);
    }

    return Response::json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Auth succeeded'], 200);
});
```

Comment: This is close but no cigar. I realize it does this. However I am looking to return a JSON response only on failure. This will either return a string of "invalid credentials" or a json representation of a user on success. I want a json response on failure and nothing on success

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it was closest to what I was looking for. Please update with my working code.

Comment: You should always return a response, even if auth doesn't fail. See my updated answer.

Comment: See that is the thing. My authentication isn't seperate from my other call. Im not making an auth call and THEN making a service call. I have built authorization INTO my handshake for my service call. So on success it will just return the response from the REST service

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps. Instead of simply returning Auth::onceBasic, do a simple if-else there:

if(Auth::onceBasic) 
return Your-Defined-Json-Response-Success 
else 
return Your-Defined-Json-Response-Success

Comment: if else will not work on this because Auth::onceBasic actually does a header call to force basic authentication....while checking the logic in an if-else it will see it as an object and always return true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this:

```
Route::filter('auth.api', function() {
    Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
    $result = json_encode(Auth::onceBasic('username'));
    return $result;
});
```

As long as `Auth::onceBasic('usersname');` returns an object or array ie `'key' => 'value'` if should be encode-able by `json_encode`. Give that a try and see what happens. Also, try var_dumping or dding `dd($result);` to see what it says.

Comment: Auth::onceBasic() returns null on success and displays "Invalid credentials" on failure